# Create a visual studio breakpoint that pauses for one second and then continues

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The topic says it all. Sometimes i just want to take a quick look and then continue, especially when a code line get hit several times. Can i automate the *press-manually-f5-to-continue-after-a-second*?

Comment: I don't see how this will do you any good. You want to "take a quick look" at *what*? If you are interested in the values of variables, just print them to the Output or Immediate Window.

Comment: Its about control flow, i can quickly see which path is taken when e.g. debugging callback handling. Or other scenarios. I can imagine many use cases for such a breakpoint. Xcode has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a breakpoint an select "When Hit...":

[image]

You can run a macro like this:

```
Sub Sleep1s()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

Or you can call 11 times {System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(90)} in the message. (Because VS debugger doesn't allow for expression to run for more than 100 ms).

But sleeping this way will block the main IDE UI thread. I don't know is it acceptable for you.